# Pipe input to process which requires it later

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, password

I cannot help myself with this issue.
I am looking for a way to pipe input (password) into command which internally executes other commands, and one of those commands requires the input.

I tried `echo 'some_password' | molecule create`,

also some variations with tee, but nothing helped as I am still stuck at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/getpass.py:91: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
  passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
```

I'm thankful for any advice.

Comment: You are going to have to show us what you have tried and what happened. We don't know what is in the command. What the various commands are. What the normal way of running that command is. ...

Comment: It is about python library that can test ansible roles. 
`molecule create` is internally executing some checks and  ansible playbook for instance creation and that is where i need to pass the echoed password but it seems that it is flushed before that.

Comment: [`man 1 expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Comment: Edit the question. Make it clear.